# Selenium Headless Firefox - Very Slow

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, debian, geckodriver

I am trying to fetch some web data using Selenium to run Firefox in headless mode in a Python3 script. I am running the script on Debian.

The code works fine, but is very very slow. Half a minute to get the title of the webpage. I need to use this in a production environment and it won't work if it's that slow. I am new to Selenium so it may be a basic mistake I am making...

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from decimal import Decimal

start_time = time.time()

fireFoxOptions = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
fireFoxOptions.set_headless()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=fireFoxOptions)

fetchUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/CakCity-Military-Waterproof-Luminous-Stopwatch/dp/B018HTGSN8/ref=sxin_1_ac_d_rm?ac_md=0-0-d2F0Y2g%3D-ac_d_rm&keywords=watch&pd_rd_i=B018HTGSN8&pd_rd_r=ad451c0c-abfe-4436-bee4-d11f9e1dbb1e&pd_rd_w=J9Zl5&pd_rd_wg=AqMuw&pf_rd_p=ed481207-4bea-4e19-bbad-73ed40fdc292&pf_rd_r=A7B9299YFYD1G0JZ81YH&psc=1&qid=1573502062"

browser.get( fetchUrl )

print ( browser.title )

executionTime = round(time.time() - start_time, 2)
print( "- execution time [" + str( executionTime ) + "]" )

browser.close()

browser.quit()
```

Execution time varies from 20s to 30s

- Debian 9.4 (Stretch)
- Firefox 70.0.1
- Geckodriver 0.26.0
- Selenium 3.141.0
- Python 3.5.3

I have tried limiting the libraries I import, and it has no change.

I have tested several different websites, such as just google.com, and the response time is the same. I can load these sites within seconds manually through any browser, so I would think headless mode would be faster. The script does not throw any errors.

Gecko log

```
1573530232430   mozrunner::runner   

INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileKfYEBK"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1573530233337   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org 

WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1573530233337   

addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org 

WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1573530233338   

addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org 

WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1573530233338   

addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org 

WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
1573530237793   Marionette  

INFO    Listening on port 36801
1573530237852   Marionette  

WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
[Parent 1707, Gecko_IOThread] 

WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /builds/worker/workspace/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 728
1573530254051   

Marionette  

INFO    Stopped listening on port 36801
```

I researched all of the warnings listed above with mixed ideas on solutions.

The "pipe error" does not always show up in the logs, seems random. Also unusual as it says chromium, but I am using Firefox...

I am unclear on the permission errors even after reading up on them, some say to just disregard them as not important.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I am experiencing the same thing.

Comment: No I still have the long delay to get simple data.

Comment: Running into same problem.

Comment: Running also into the same issue